# WebRequest.RegisterPrefix for http:// returns true, doesn't work

Tags: networking, windows-phone-7

I'm trying to use [`WebRequest.RegisterPrefix`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.registerprefix%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) to register a decorator [`IWebRequestCreate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.iwebrequestcreate%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) implementation with the intention being to add "debug" scenarios (like emulating different connectivity scenarios).

I'm using the Mango beta 2 SDK and the `RegisterPrefix` method always returns true when used with "http://" as a prefix (or "http" for that matter), but the registered IWebRequestCreate instance is not being used.

I can see from the documentation that it should return false for duplicates, but it doesn't seem to be functioning as documented.

Is there any other way of achieving what I'm after in a way that is transparent to consumers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm using `WebRequest.RegisterPrefix` for unit testing, registering an `IWebRequestCreate` implementation for a prefix of `test://`, and this does work.

I found that after registering an `IWebRequestCreate` for `http://`, calling `WebRequest.Create` with an `http://` uri would return a request created from the registered `IWebRequestCreate`, but calling `WebRequest.CreateHttp` would still return an `HttpWebRequest`.

The following code should verify this, and I'm using the Mango Beta 2 SDK (6-29-11):

```
public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    public class FakeRequest : WebRequest
    {
        private Uri _uri;

        public FakeRequest(Uri uri)
        {
            _uri = uri;
        }

        public override Uri RequestUri { get { return _uri; } }
    }

    public class FakeRequestFactory : IWebRequestCreate
    {
        public WebRequest Create(Uri uri)
        {
            return new FakeRequest(uri);
        }
    }

    // Constructor
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // returns System.Net.Browser.ClientHttpWebRequest
        var request1 = WebRequest.Create("http://www.foo.com");

        // returns System.Net.Browser.ClientHttpWebRequest
        var request2 = WebRequest.CreateHttp("http://www.foo.com"); 

        // returns true
        bool result1 = WebRequest.RegisterPrefix("http://", new FakeRequestFactory());

        // returns FakeRequest
        var request3 = WebRequest.Create("http://www.foo.com");

        // returns System.Net.Browser.ClientHttpWebRequest
        var request4 = WebRequest.CreateHttp("http://www.foo.com");

        // returns false
        bool result2 = WebRequest.RegisterPrefix("http://", new FakeRequestFactory());

        // returns false, as per the note in the documention
        bool result3 = HttpWebRequest.RegisterPrefix("http://", new FakeRequestFactory());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey I know this question is 2 years old but I came across the same problem. I think you'll find that `WebRequest.RegisterPrefix()` **does** return false if you try to register `http:` (notice the single colon, no forward slashes). If I ever find a workaround, I'll try to remember to update this post.

**EDIT**

In my particular case I wanted to throw out `System.Net.FtpWebRequest` and roll my own FTP client implementation (because the framework's implementation [sucks](http://mattmitchell.com.au/ftpwebrequest-is-broken/)).

In order to do that, I used reflection (and a bunch of late binding tricks) to get the arraylist of registered prefix and remove the ones that are linked to the internal `System.Net.FtpWebRequestCreator` class.

I'm not sure if all of these APIs are available for windows phone, but here's what I did:

```
Type webRequest = typeof(System.Net.WebRequest);
Assembly system = Assembly.GetAssembly(webRequest);
Type ftpWebRequestCreator = system.GetType("System.Net.FtpWebRequestCreator");
ArrayList prefixList = (ArrayList)webRequest.GetProperty("PrefixList", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic).GetValue(null, null);

IEnumerator enumerator = prefixList.GetEnumerator();
while (enumerator != null && enumerator.MoveNext()) {
    if (object.ReferenceEquals(enumerator.Current.Creator.GetType(), ftpWebRequestCreator)) {
        prefixList.Remove(enumerator.Current);
        if (System.Net.WebRequest.RegisterPrefix(enumerator.Current.Prefix, new CustomWebRequestCreator())) {
            enumerator = null;
        } else {
            enumerator = prefixList.GetEnumerator();
        }
    }
}

// Now I can use Create() on the base class
System.Net.WebRequest myCustomWebRequest = System.Net.WebRequest.Create("ftp://example.com/public");
```

This works by finding all prefixes that are registered with `FtpWebRequestCreator` and replacing them with my own creator. It should be fairly straightforward to adapt this for http(s).

Answer (score -1):

The phone *only* has a client stack so RegisterPrefix has no effect on the phone.

Comment: What about registering custom protocols? If it's not implemented, shouldn't they remove the API or throw a NotSupportedException?

Comment: The API isn't about different protocols, it only changes existing protocols (https/http). Since there is only one stack it does what is expected. The reason it doesn't throw NotSupported is that it does what it says it does (so that shared code between desktop and phone doesn't break).

Comment: If it's only about swapping between client/browser implementations, why not use an enum rather than an interface? Why give the false perception of extensibility?

Comment: It's because you're matching partial prefixes.  In desktop Silverlight this allows you to have browser stack for some calls (e.g. prefix = http://myserver.com/) and client stack when you need that functionality (e.g. PUT/DELETE) for REST (prefix = https://api.ebay.com).  Does that help?

Comment: I understand the `baseUri` argument. I'm saying that if they don't actually intend for me to use a custom `IWebRequestCreate` instance, why use an interface? Give me the choice using an enumeration instead.

Comment: I don't know the intention, but I imagine it's either for future expansion or compatibility with desktop CLR.

Comment: This is actually incorrect. `RegisterPrefix` _does_ work, but `WebCreate.CreateHttp` ignores it (`WebCreate.Create` does not).